# What mobile lightning wallets show the user the preimage?

Tags: lightning-network, bitcoin-wallet-app, invoices

It seems like most mobile lightning wallets don't make the preimage accessible to the user after a lightning invoice is paid, other than Muun. Does anyone know of any others that do?

Comment: When checking the **Breez** lightning wallet on an iPhone, it is possible to view the payment preimage for both incoming and outgoing transactions. While I cannot confirm it, I would anticipate that both the **Phoenix** and **Zap** wallets also offer access to the payment preimage.

Answer (score 0):

If you use your own node you can use the Zeus mobile app, which will show you the preimage if you need it. Zeus devs are right now working on olympusln, possibly this will give you a similar feature without running your own node soon.